# How do I get the title using substr with two string in different position

Tags: php, title

Example Title: Anime Title : Episode 01, Subbed 01

Hi I'm trying to get the "Episode 01" in the title but i'm having trouble with substr() function how do I declare the command on it?

```
$Updated =  get_the_title();
if ( strpos( $Updated , ":" ) && ( strripos( $Updated, "," ) ) ) {
  // this is the line I'm having trouble to deal with
  $Updated = substr( $Updated , strpos( $Updated , ":" ) + 1 );
} else if ( strpos( $Updated , ":" ) ) {
  $Updated = substr( $Updated , strpos( $Updated , ":" ) + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is not really a WP question and should probably be asked on a PHP or general programming forum.

What I can garner from the code you provide is that you believe there will always be a colon `:` and sometimes there may be a comma `,`, you may want to take a look at [`expode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) rather than [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) + [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

First, to answer your question, you'd need the location of the comma as well so you can tell `substr()` where to stop.

```
$updated = get_the_title();
// calculate the string positions once rather than multiple times
// first colon
$colon_pos = strpos( $updated, ':' );
// first comma AFTER the colon
$comma_pos = strpos( $updated, ',', $colon_pos );

// MUST compare strpos values to false, it can return 0 (zero) which is falsy
if ( $colon_pos !== false && $comma_pos !== false ) {
  // start from the colon position plus 1
  // use comma position as the length, since it is based on the offset of the colon
  $updated = substr( $updated, $colon_pos + 1, $comma_pos );
} else if ( $colon_pos !== false ) {
  $updated = substr( $updated, $colon_pos + 1 );
}
```

As mentioned at the beginning, this could all be simplified with `explode()`:

```
// - first, split the title on the first colon ':', the second/last item of
// that action will be everything after the colon if there is a colon, or
// the whole title if there is no colon
// - second, grab that last item and split it on commas, the first/zeroth
// item of that action will be the episode
// - finally, trim off the excess whitespace
$updated = explode( ':', get_the_title(), 2 );
$updated = trim( explode( ',', end( $updated ) )[0] );
```

Long form:

```
$updated = get_the_title();             // the full title string
$updated = explode( ':', $updated, 2 ); // split it in two around the first ':'
$updated = end( $updated );             // grab the last element of the split
$updated = explode( ',', $updated );    // split the remainder on ','
$updated = trim( $updated[0] );         // get the first item after the split and remove excess whitespace
```

I hope that's not too confusing.

Comment: I actually solved my problem instead of using explode i used str_replac and trim it but this is more simpler to read, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function in a manner like this:

`function.php`:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

`template_file.php`:

```
$Updated = get_the_title();
$Updated = get_string_between($Updated , ":", ",");
echo $Updated;
```